# Module installed by Luarocks not found

Tags: module, lua, luarocks

I am working on Debian Stable Linux. I installed luafilesystem module by command:

```bash
luarocks --local install luafilesystem
```

However, it is not found when any of following is used in lua source files:

```lua
require ("lfs")
require ("luafilesystem")
```

(Although these files run properly when ran from within ZeroBraneStudio IDE).

From a suggestion on the web, I ran following command also:

```bash
luarocks --local install luarocks
```

But it does not help. I checked with luarocks-admin command, which showed:

```
CONFIGURATION
    Lua version: 5.1
    Configuration files:
        System: /etc/luarocks/config.lua (ok)
        User  : /home/abcd/.luarocks/config-5.1.lua (not found)

    Rocks trees in use: 
        /home/abcd/.luarocks
        /usr/local
```

Currently, I only have these 2 modules installed:

```
$ luarocks list

Installed rocks:
----------------

luafilesystem
   1.7.0-2 (installed) - /home/abcd/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks

luarocks
   2.4.3-1 (installed) - /home/abcd/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

Should I copy /etc/luarocks/config.lua to /home/abcd/.luarocks for this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you `require "luarocks.loader"` first?

Comment: I installed modules using `sudo luarocks install luafilesystem` (without --local option) and it works. So luarocks.loader is needed for locally installed modules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` environment variables control the paths searched by lua when looking for packages.  These are probably not set correctly.  Include the paths used by luarocks in these variables by running

```
eval "$(luarocks path)"
```

and you should be all set.

Answer (score 3):

Eval works fine when executing the code from the terminal, but it doesn't work when executing it using the vscode debugger.

To get around this problem, I did the following.

```
local LUA_PATH = 'my LUA_PATH from "$ luarocks path"'
local LUA_CPATH = 'my LUA_CPATH from "$ luarocks path"'

package.path = package.path .. ';' .. LUA_PATH
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ';' .. LUA_CPATH
```

With this change, I can run the code using the debugger.